# solr - only highligt matched words in results

Tags: solr

My parameters query:

```
q = (subject:zielone AND subject:aaaaa) OR subject:czerwone
hl=true
hl.fl=subject,description
```

First part query: (subject:zielone AND subject:aaaaa) return 0 results (it's ok)

Second part query: OR subject:czerwone return many documents (it's ok)

but when I look to highlight section, I have:

```
"4037903":{
  "subject":["<em>zielone</em> <em>czerwone</em>"]},
"4040790":{
  "subject":["<em>zielone</em> <em>czerwone</em>"]},
"4228003":{
  "subject":["<em>zielone</em> <em>czerwone</em>"]},
```

I wants only the words highlighted have been found:

```
"4037903":{
  "subject":["zielone <em>czerwone</em>"]},
"4040790":{
  "subject":["zielone <em>czerwone</em>"]},
"4228003":{
  "subject":["zielone <em>czerwone</em>"]},
```

How did it get?

The same problem (but no answer):
[How to prevent solr from highlighting unmatched terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913854/how-to-prevent-solr-from-highlighting-unmatched-terms)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [`requireFieldMatch`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.requireFieldMatch):

> If true, then a field will only be highlighted if the query matched in
>   this particular field (normally, terms are highlighted in all
>   requested fields regardless of which field matched the query). This
>   only takes effect if "hl.usePhraseHighlighter" is "true".
>
> The default value is "false".

To see all the highlighting parameters, you can go to the [Solr documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters).

Comment: mhmm, first part query (subject:zielone AND subject:aaaaa), never find any document, so I dosn't want highlighting these words in any returned field. I want only these words that have been hit (subject:czerwone). I tested requireFieldMatch and hl.usePhraseHighlighter they do not give this effect

Answer (score 0):

Check on the link for highlighting

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.requireFieldMatch